# Adding new table to mysql replication

Tags: mysql, replication

Hi I have an existing mysql master-master replication between 3 servers and all the servers are connected to each other. I'm replicating some tables in a specific database. there is about 80 tables in this database and only 10 of them is replicating. I'm using replicate-do-table option in my mysql config file to tell mysql which tables should be replicated.

In this stage I found that I need another table to be replicated which was not replicated before. When I add new table to mysql config file, Newly added data are coming to all the server but old existing data are not coming. what should I do to bring older data to all the servers.

this is my mysql config file

```
    default_table_encryption=ON
    table_encryption_privilege_check=ON
    replica_parallel_workers=4
    enforce_gtid_consistency=ON
    gtid_mode=ON
    keyring_file_data=.....
    early-plugin-load=keyring_file.so
    skip_replica_start=OFF
    auto_increment_increment=50
    auto_increment_offset=1
    server_id=3
    replicate_same_server_id=0
    replicate-do-db=db
    replicate-do-table=db.table1
    replicate-do-table=db.table2
    replicate-do-table=db.table3
    replicate-do-table=db.table4
    replicate-do-table=db.table5
    replicate-do-table=db.table6
    replicate-do-table=db.table7
    replicate-do-table=db.table8
    replicate-do-table=db.table9
    replicate-do-table=db.table10
    replicate-do-table=db.table11
    replicate-do-table=db.table12
    slave-skip-errors=1032
```

Comment: Can you share the line(s) in your mysql configuration file showing your replicate-do-table setting and any other replication filtering variables?

Comment: The basic idea is that you copy the old/existing data from the existing server to the new server and then start replication to capture changes going forward. The specific method depends on the version you are using. Here is a guide from the docs for 8.0, for example: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-replication-excerpt/8.0/en/replication-howto-existingdata.html